# Best tuning for load from source (mysqldump)

Tags: mysql, performance, dump

Beyond disabling autocommit, or  separating the source file and the data folder of MySQL in different disks, are there any other general tips in order to improve the performance when we load a lot of information (mysqldump of 150Gb.), some variables to (specially) keep in mind for this kind of operation?
I’m working with one MySQL 5.7 over Ubuntu 16.04, 8Gb. of RAM and two pairs of SATA 5400 rpm :-( in RAID 1.

Comment: If this is a one-time task, why do you care how long it takes?  150GB takes a long time to read on 5400rpm drives.

Comment: I have to repeat the same task with almost ten databases (dumps greater than 100Gb.). I know these aren’t the best devices but I have to manage with it. I’m experienced with production environments with different type of load, but it’s the first time I deal with this dumps.

Comment: You will probably find that it goes at 100% I/O.  So, no MySQL tuning could help.